# AppDelegates function "supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor" does not get called on iPads

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

In my AppDelegate I am using a function to rotate my device and lock the orientation.

iPhone shall be portrait only, and iPad landscape only.

It works on iPhones, but the following function does never get called on iPads:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    print("Test")
    return AppDelegate.orientationLock
}
```

I think it was working on iPads before I switched to "SwiftUI Life Cicle" but I am not absolutely sure if this was the point of time, where it stopped working:

```
 @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

The info.plist is also set to "Landscape only" for iPads, but the app starts in portrait mode anyway, which is strange too:

[image: info.plist]

Comment: If your app supports multitasking, the system doesn’t call `application(_:supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor:)` on your view controller because multitasking apps must support all orientations. You can opt out of multitasking by enabling Requires full screen on your iOS target or by not declaring support for all possible orientations within the Info.plist file.- [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations)

Comment: lorem ipsum's answer was very helpful and the correct answer for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set this key in my info.plist to false, so that `application(_:supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor:)` gets called on iPads:

```
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
```

Thanks @lorem ipsum for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue in iPad, And got solution.

In your Info.Plist make this setting.
[image]

or
In your **Project > General**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is exactly what I have inside my info.plist file (see screenshot above) and which does not seem to have any effect. I want landscape only for iPads.